# code works in test, but not on production

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, iis-6

One of our view model files needed an update to the code (simple if stmt), and our fix works fine in test. However when we deployed to production, the fix failed, and acts as if the code isn't there, even though it is (we see the 2 updated files with the changes on the server).

We've copied over the production db to test and again, it works in test (and locally), but still not in production.

It's an mvc site, c#, iis 6.0, sql server 2008, and we're stumped as to what to even try again. We've even tried changing the .cshtml file, putting in hidden vars, but when executed on the site, we can't find the vars, or the subtle changes we put in.

Any hints on what else we might be able to try to get this to work?

Comment: are you updating the application DLL in the `bin` folder on the production server?

Comment: how do you deploy your mvc application? web deploy? ftp?

Comment: Yes, dll is updated on prod.

Comment: We deploy by first building the application in the release mode in visual studio. Then we copy the bin, Content, Controllers, Helpers, Views, Global.asax, Global.asax.cs over to the folder on the production server.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a caching issue? Have you tried App Pool Recycle and clearing appropriate caches?

Comment: In my experience, IIS can be a little stubborn about caching. It's very reluctant to let go of things; we've had several cases where even after restarting app pools and sending every cache-clear command we could find, the fix was to go home and try again in the morning when IIS has decided to drop the cached version.

Comment: No go on the App Pool Recycle or clearing the caches. We did leave it over the weekend and it's still no change either. . .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You say your .cshtml file does not show changes. This can mean:

- You are not on your production server, find the correct server
- The dir you are in is not the website dir, check iis to find the correct location of your site
- Stop iis server before and start your and after you make changes

Comment: No, we're def on the production server and we see the files. We also can't restart iis and there are other sites hosted here, and this is production.

Comment: If you add files to a bin dir you will restart the application. All your sites should have there own app pool.